# Spring @Cacheable and @Async annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache, completable-future, spring-async

I have the need to cache some the results of some asynchronous computations. In detail, to overcome this issue, I am trying to use Spring 4.3 cache and asynchronous computation features.

As an example, let's take the following code:

```
@Service
class AsyncService {
    @Async
    @Cacheable("users")
    CompletableFuture<User> findById(String usedId) {
        // Some code that retrieves the user relative to id userId
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(user);
    }
}
```

Is it possible? I mean, will the caching abstraction of Spring handle correctly the objects of type `CompletableFuture<User>`? I know that [Caffeine Cache](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/caffeine/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/AsyncLoadingCache.java) has something like that, but I can't understand if Spring uses it if properly configured.

**EDIT**: I am not interested in the `User` object itself, but in the `CompletableFuture` that represents the computation.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I have to try it in these days. @Kayaman, I will let you know the results of my tests.

Comment: Good. I've been waiting to see if anyone took the ball here. Did some light googling myself, but only found out the `Future` vs. `CompatibleFuture` in `@Async` tasks that was fixed in `4.2`.

Comment: @Kayaman I post an answer with my results. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [SPR-12967](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12967), `ListenableFuture` (`CompletableFuture`) are not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the Jira that you linked was asked a different question. As far as I understand, in the Jira the user is asking for caching the internal value of the `ListenableFuture`. I think that as long as `CompletableFuture` honors the contract of `Object`, it can be successfully cached, can't it?

Answer (score 12):

The community asks me to do some experiments, so I made them. I found that the answer to my question is simple: `@Cacheable` and `@Async` do not work together if they are placed above the same method.

To be clear, I was not asking for a way to directly make the cache return the object owned by a `CompletableFuture`. This is impossible, and if it isn't so, it will break the contract of *asynchronous computation* of the `CompletableFuture` class.

As I said, the two annotations do not work together on the same method. If you think about it, it is obvious. Marking with `@Async` is also `@Cacheable` means to delegate the whole cache management to different asynchronous threads. If the computation of the value of the `CompletableFuture` will take a long time to complete, the value in the cache will be placed after that time by Spring Proxy.

Obviously, there is a workaround. The workaround uses the fact the `CompletableFuture` is a *promise*. Let's have a look at the code below.

```
@Component
public class CachedService {
    /* Dependecies resolution code */
    private final AsyncService service;

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "ints")
    public CompletableFuture<Integer> randomIntUsingSpringAsync() throws InterruptedException {
        final CompletableFuture<Integer> promise = new CompletableFuture<>();
        // Letting an asynchronous method to complete the promise in the future
        service.performTask(promise);
        // Returning the promise immediately
        return promise;
    }
}

@Component
public class AsyncService {
    @Async
    void performTask(CompletableFuture<Integer> promise) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        // Completing the promise asynchronously
        promise.complete(random.nextInt(1000));
    }
}
```

The trick is to create an incomplete promise and return it immediately from the method marked with the `@Cacheable` annotation. The promise will be completed asynchronously by another bean that owns the method marked with the `@Async` annotation.

As a bonus, I also implemented a solution that does not use the Spring `@Async` annotation, but it uses the factory methods available in the `CompletableFuture` class directly.

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "ints1")
public CompletableFuture<Integer> randomIntNativelyAsync() throws
        InterruptedException {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::getAsyncInteger, executor);
}

private Integer getAsyncInteger() {
    logger.info("Entering performTask");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return random.nextInt(1000);
}
```

Anyway, I shared the complete solution to my GitHub problem, [spring-cacheable-async](https://github.com/rcardin/spring-cacheable-async).

Finally, the above is a long description of what the Jira [SPR-12967](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12967) refers to.

I hope it helps.
Cheers.

Comment: I upvoted you for trying, but what you’re doing looks like a hack. It’d be clearer to let go of the `Cacheable` annotation and use the cache manager directly. Or register a callback that does.

Comment: The mechanisms under the hood of `@Cacheable` annotation are very useful. I am using Spring, so I am trying to do things following its philosophy.

Answer (score 2):

Add `@Async` annotation on methods in one class and `@Cacheable` annotation at method level in a different class.

Then invoke `@Async` method from a service or any different layer.

It worked for me, both Redis cache and Async, which improved the performance drastically.

Comment: Hi @Rohit, welcome to Stack Overflow. From what I understand, this is similar to the solution we have also implemented on our project. However I think it would be nice to add a bit of code to illustrate your solution, and be more specific in the descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Please add annotation @EnableAsync at @Component or @Serice class levele.
Exp:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@EnableAsync //Add it to here
public class CachingServiceImpl implements CachingService {
```

Hope to help you!

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it would work as long as

- the implementation of CacheManager behind the `@Cacheable` is not serializing the cached objects (like a cache backed by Hazelcast)
- Since the `CompletableFuture` holds a state, which can be modified by calling e.g. the `cancel()` method, it's important that all the users of the API won't mess around with the cached object. Otherwise, there might be the risk that the cached object inside the `Future` could not be retrieved anymore, and a cache eviction would be necessary
- It's worth to verify in which order the proxies behind the annotations are called. i.e. is the `@Cacheable` proxy called always before the `@Async` one? Or the other way around? Or it depends? For example, if the `@Async` is called before, it will fire a `Callable` inside a `ForkJoinPool`, just to then retrieve the other object from the cache.

Comment: Nope, it does not work. Today I made some experiments. Tomorrow I will post the results of such experiments

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below approach and it seems to work.

- create a method with `@Cachable` which does the actual business logic
- create a method with `@Async` which calls the above `@Cachable` method and returns a `CompletableFuture`
- call the method with `@Async` in your main execution flow

Example:

```
public class Main {
    public void cachedAsyncData() {
        try {
            asyncFetcher.getData().get();
        } catch(Exception e){}
    }
}

public class AsyncFetcher {
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<String> getData() {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(cacheFetcher.getData());
    }
}

public class CacheFetcher {
    @Cacheable
    public String getData() {
        return "DATA";
    }
}
```